# Google OAuth redirect URL mismatch

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I've followed a sample created here:

https://github.com/googlesamples/oauth-apps-for-windows/blob/master/OAuthDesktopApp/README.md

to have Google OAuth work with my desktop application and it seems I got stuck with redirect URIs. I know I have to provide a RedirectURI on Google Credentials page (in Developers Console), but I cannot figure out how to provide a RedirectURI to accept any port number.

In this sample, a local HTTP server opens a connection on localhost (127.0.0.1) and it seems to work, no matter which port is used for listening (it finds some random port and then sends RedirectURI as localhost:randomport) and authentication works as expected. However, when I try to do that in my application, I get notification that RedirectURI is not defined. Is there any special syntax to be used when defining RedirectURI inside Developer Console?

Comment: Desktop applications are installed applications you shouldn't need a redirect URI, its basically defaulted to localhost.  Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment pointed me in the right direction. I had Web Application OAuth Credentials created, instead of Desktop. It works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the read me for the sample you are following

> Create a new OAuth 2.0 client, select Other

You should have created a oauth2 client of type other, not an web application.  the only difference really is that other is intended for desktop or native applications which use localhost by default as the redirect uri.

Comment: Looks like I missed this part. Thank you. Only now you can actually select "Desktop app" as an Application Type, not Other.

Comment: Your following a really old project that hasnt been updated in a while.